# How do I retrieve a value from a JSON string using gatling JsonPath.query?

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

Given a string:

```
val json = """{"id":"derp"}"""
```

When I try to retrieve the value of ID using JsonPath I get the empty iterator

```
import io.gatling.jsonpath.JsonPath

JsonPath.query("$.id", json).right.get
// Iterator[Any] = empty iterator
```

How do I get the value of id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the type of the second arg to `JsonPath.query` is `Any`, this function does not seem to support multiple types of arguments. It does not parse the input string, but expects it already to be parsed. Looks a bit weird as design choice.

So, supposing that Jackson is used as the parser lib, the following will work and select the value under `id` key:

```
val json = """{"id":"derp"}"""
val parsed = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, classOf[Object])

// to retrieve the ids as a list:
val ids = JsonPath.query("$.id", parsed).right.get.toList

// the only "id" result of the query
val id = ids.head
```

Comment: That seems to work, but how do I get the value from the iterator?

Comment: The value of `id` from the iterator?